# Why do `wq!` and `q!` causing "E855 Autocommands caused command to abort" on any Python files?

Tags: autocmd, linux-ubuntu, quit

Executing `:q!` and `:wq!` (of course `:x` as well) on any Python files causing "**E855: Autocommands caused command to abort**". However, `:qa` , `:wqa` (and of course `:xa` as well) don't caused the same error, my guess because they safe all buffers (files) before quitting. But I don't get it because I don't have multiple files opened anyway, just one file, so why `:wq!` doesn't work ? This screenshot is a sample error from trying to quit using `:wq!` :

[image: (screenshot)]

Not many suggestions I could find on **E855**, but [one suggested](https://github.com/ets-labs/python-vimrc/issues/32) to disable Python tagbar close in vimrc to make `:wq!` work :

```
autocmd BufWinLeave *.py :TagbarClose
```

I did disable it (line 156 in my vimrc, here's [my full settings](https://gist.github.com/nowhere-girl/47850098e93abff5f85f4bed11218204) if necessary) but the problem persists. The only autocommands I have left in my `.vimrc` are for highlighting, therefore I'm not sure what other autocommands caused the error :

```
    augroup vimrc_autocmds
        autocmd!
        autocmd FileType python,rst,c,cpp highlight Excess ctermbg=DarkGrey guibg=Black
        autocmd FileType python,rst,c,cpp match Excess /\%81v.*/
        autocmd FileType python,rst,c,cpp set nowrap
        autocmd FileType python,rst,c,cpp set colorcolumn=80
    augroup END
```

I have 2 questions :

1. My muscle memory can't seem to let go of `:wq!`, is there any modification in vimrc I could do to make `:wq!` work ?
2. I'm not familiar with Python yet, why doesn't this error occur with my C++ and C files but only Python ?

Comment: Check your autocommands: `:au BufWinLeave` `:au BufLeave` `:au BufWritePost`   `:au BufWritePost` `:au ExitPre` (and possibly others as well that I do not remember currently). Did you add any specific such autocommands for python files? Note: those could also be in plugins you are using

Comment: Does this happen on `:wq` without the bang? Re muscle memory: why the bang? Have you considered `ZZ`? Have you tried [Debugging your vimrc](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2003/10604)?

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt Hi, thanks. I had only `autocmd BufWinLeave` and `autocmd BufEnter` for tagbar open and close, but I've disabled them as I mentioned in my post. I don't have any `:au` commands in my vimrc.  I have autocommands in my Python settings but it's for highlighting (posted above). There's no other autocommands except for the highlighting autocommands I posted above (my full vimrc is also posted).

Comment: @D.BenKnoble (1) Yes, it happens with `:wq` as well. (2) Force of habit of supressing warnings (3) Personal preference, unlike `ZZ`,  `:wq!` will always save even if there's no modification, therefore updating my last edit time which is important for my work. Also, this problem happens with `ZZ` as well. (4) I haven't, but now I will start to investigate my plugins. Thank you.

Comment: I didn’t look closely, but it seems odd that you have two plugin managers and that you tell one to use the autoload directory to put plugins in (which is probably just wrong…)